# How to sort array according to age

Tags: javascript

I have gone through the stackoverflow questions and have found answers that are similar/close to the issue I am having, but it seems my understanding is lacking.

I have an array that consist of ages (4, 21, 47, 16, 18 etc). I am trying to sort the array so that it would find every index position that is under 18. I have writen a for loop for this, but it terminates everytime there is a age over 18.

```
var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.length && myArray[i] < 18; i++) {
text += i;
}
console.log(text);
text = ""; // with this I get answer 0 to console, where as i would want
0 3.
```

I have also tried following, but these will give me only the first value under 18 (or not work in general). I have just started coding so I dont understand these ways as well so I would prefer to do it with for loop if possible:

1)

```
function underEighteen() {
myArray.reduce(function a, e, i) {
if (e < 18)
a.push(i);
return a;
}, []);
}
```

2)

```
function isUnderEighteen(elementBelow18) {
return elementBelow18;
}
function sortAge() {
var under18 = myArray.find(isUnderEighteen);
}
```

I have tried several other simple ways to sort the array to no avail. Help appreciated! Javascript only...

edit: So I have a plain web page with a textbox where you can insert age&name and save them. Then I have a possibility to show everyone who are not allowed to buy alcohol and those who are (under and over 18).

My aim is to do this so that I find the index positions of those elements that are under 18, pull the same elements from name array that correspond those of the age arrays on post them on the page with:

```
document.getElementbyId("notAllowetoDrink").innerHTML = "Do not sell    
alcohol + "XXXXXXX;
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Can you give us an example input and expected output so we understand exactly what you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly - duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> with this I get answer 0 to console, where as i would want 0 3.

and

> I have also tried following, but these will give me only the first
>   value under 18 (or not work in general).

You were **close**, small issues are highlighted in comments

```
function underEighteen() {
   return myArray.reduce(function (a, e, i) { //return was missing and function syntax was incorrect
      if (e < 18)
      {
         a.push(i);
      }
      return a;
   }, []);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var myArray = [4, 21, 47, 16, 18];

function underEighteen() {
  return myArray.reduce(function(a, e, i) {
    if (e < 18) {
      a.push(i);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(underEighteen());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your `reduce` approach and return the result.

```js
function underEighteen(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(a, e, i) {
        if (e < 18) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
}

var ages = [4, 21, 47, 16, 18];

console.log(underEighteen(ages));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `filter()` instead of `sort()`.

```js
var arr = [4, 21, 47, 16, 18];

function under18(array){
  return array.filter(function(x){return x < 18;});
}
console.log(under18(arr));
```

```css
.as-console {
    height: 100%;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

This will be the base code, you can either use the array directly or pass to the function as a local variable!

Comment: @qinqa Does this help you?

Comment: Hi, with this one I got the ages literally (the answer console.log was [ 4, 16] where I was looking for the "positions with in the array" [0, 3]. gurvinder372 example works for that cause. (Now I´am just trying to get the values of 0,3 from the name array that still holds 5 names with something like myArrayName.slice(under18) -> var under18 = underEighteen;) Nonetheless TY for your help!

Comment: @no problem, please close answer if your issue is solved!

Comment: will do when I find out how! :D